# Strange C++ syntax in vulkan-hpp

Tags: c++

I have been having a look into the vulkan-hpp source code to try to understand how to manage `StructureChain`s. I've found this odd looking syntax (line marked with comment) related with the usage of `template` keyword as a member type. Moreover, its followed by a function call with no `;` preceding.

```
  template<typename X, typename Y, typename ...Z, typename Dispatch>
  VULKAN_HPP_INLINE StructureChain<X, Y, Z...> PhysicalDevice::getFormatProperties2( VULKAN_HPP_NAMESPACE::Format format, Dispatch const &d ) const VULKAN_HPP_NOEXCEPT
  {
    StructureChain<X, Y, Z...> structureChain;
    VULKAN_HPP_NAMESPACE::FormatProperties2& formatProperties = structureChain.template get<VULKAN_HPP_NAMESPACE::FormatProperties2>(); //This line
    d.vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties2( m_physicalDevice, static_cast<VkFormat>( format ), reinterpret_cast<VkFormatProperties2*>( &formatProperties ) );
    return structureChain;
  }
```

Can anyone help me to figure out the meaning of this line?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `template` keyword is used to disambiguate the following expression as a template instantiation.

`structureChain` type depends on template parameters, so the compiler cannot know how to interpret the following `get<VULKAN_HPP_NAMESPACE::FormatProperties2` expression, which may be an instantiation of a `get` template, or comparison expression. The `template` keyword indicates that `get` is a template, and the following is a template instantiation. In the absence of this keyword the compiler would assume `get` is not a template, so the following must be a comparison expression.

See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_template_disambiguator_for_dependent_names).